# How to separate rows of csv file without "\n"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, csv

I have used following codes to separate rows in a csv file. But it turns out the csv file doesn't contain any "\n" mark, so when I ran out this code, I only got one component in "rows". But the rows are indeed shown separated in the csv file somehow (I viewed using TextEdit, and when I print out "quotes", it was also separated in rows).

```
    NSString *quotes = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"quotes.csv" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    NSArray *rows = [quotes componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

I would like to ask if there is some way to fix this csv file so that this piece of code could work. Or is there some other way to separate rows of the csv file? I am coding in Objective-C by the way. Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the file?

Comment: Is it possible that the lines are separated by `\r`s instead?

Comment: Yes! It is separated by "\r"! Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if there were a decent hex editor for Mac, but I haven't found one yet (that doesn't come with a lot of extra baggage).

Comment: @HotLicks what about [0xed](http://www.suavetech.com/0xed/)?

Comment: @ZevEisenberg -- Never seen it before -- I'll give it a look.

Comment: @HotLicks as a bonus, the icon contains a coded message. I cracked the last one, so he changed it, and I haven’t decoded it yet. It looks like executable code, but I don’t know what language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from duskwuff in the comments: the lines are separated by \r instead. So just replace "\n" with "\r" in:

> NSArray *rows = [quotes componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

Thanks guys!